# Present HUD before posting values to server

Tags: ios, objective-c, request, hud

Hi I'm using this code to send post values to a server but I want the HUD to appear during the time the request is being done, because it appears only when it ends the request.

```
-(IBAction)sendk:(id)sender {
/*HUD*/

        SLHUD *hudView = [SLHUD Mostrar:self.view]; // Creates a Hud object.
        hudView.text = @"Please Wait"; // Sets the text of the Hud.
        UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
        activityIndicator.alpha = 1.0;
        activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(160, 280);
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = NO;
        [activityIndicator setTag:899];
        [self.view addSubview:activityIndicator];
        [activityIndicator startAnimating];
        /*FIN HUD*/

        NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"user=%@&pass=%@",[username text],[password text]];

        NSLog(@"%@",post);
        NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"URL TO SERVER"];

        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:url];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];

        //[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[url host]];

        NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
        NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
        NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

        NSLog(@"%ld",(long)[response statusCode]);

        NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@",responseData);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the code is blocking the main thread until the network request finishes.  The screen will only update after the `sendk` method returns, but the method won't return until the `sendSynchronousRequest` method is finished.  The solution is to dispatch the networking code (everything after `/*FIN HUD*/`) onto a background thread, or use `sendAsynchronousRequest`, and use the completion block to notify the main thread when the response arrives.

The code framework for using a background thread looks like this

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{

    // do networking stuff here

    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        // turn off the HUD and remove the spinner here
        // also do something with the network response here

    });

});
```